# DllImport for C# (original is in C++/CLI) Need to output arrays

Tags: c#, pointers, c++-cli, dllimport

This is how it looks like in C++:

```
[DllImportAttribute("Win32DLLRecon.dll", CharSet=CharSet::Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention::StdCall)]
    extern "C" void proc1
        (__int32 *i1,
             __int16 *i2,
             __int16 *i3,
             char *i4,
             unsigned *i5,      
             unsigned char *o1, 
             unsigned __int16 *o2,
             float *o3);
```

where i = input , o = output
What would be C# equivalent?
I tried to specify like arrays, for example "out Byte [] output", but it complains that it needs byte*, not byte[]  ( I do need to use pointers at the code).
EDIT:
What will happen if I just declare my whole class as unsafe and pass these as pointers: extern proc (out Byte* output, etc)?

Comment: The argument names and comments were carefully crafted to not get you an answer.

Comment: I modified the names, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Please, can someone take a look!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to use a `System.IntPtr` for this, or a `System.IntPtr[]` for a true array.

Comment: Can I use it for Byte and SByte?  Do you have any examples? What will happen if I just declare my whole class as unsafe and pass these as pointers:  extern proc (out Byte* output, etc)?